# Flink Releasing TaskManager after some time after the program is running

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

After submitting the flink program it will run for some time. After that I am getting the below mentioned exception

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Releasing TaskManager 98fba59750780a0a7d400f5198636e3b.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:464)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at flink.KafkaFlink.main(KafkaFlink.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:420)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:404)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:781)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:275)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:210)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1020)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$9(CliFrontend.java:1096)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1096)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Releasing TaskManager 98fba59750780a0a7d400f5198636e3b.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool.releaseTaskManagerInternal(SlotPool.java:1067)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool.releaseTaskManager(SlotPool.java:1050)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.onReceive(AkkaRpcActor.java:142)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Error from task manager

```
2022-06-15 17:23:47,494 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.taskmanager.TaskManagerDetailsHandler  - Implementation error: Unhandled exception.
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.UnknownTaskExecutorException: No TaskExecutor registered under 7aa5950ae70a2e4aeef2c1240b3c3dca.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.requestTaskManagerInfo(ResourceManager.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.onReceive(AkkaRpcActor.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.onReceive(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:40)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I am using flink 1.5. What is the reason behind this exception?

Comment: Is this Flink 1.5 or 1.15? Either way, I think we need to see the task manager logs (this looks like the job manager log).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Using flink 1.5

Comment: @DavidAnderson Added task manager logs

Comment: Maybe this is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9215, which was fixed in 1.5.1. I suggest upgrading to at least 1.5.6 -- the 1.5.x series of releases had a lot of issues in this part of the stack -- and preferably something newer.